# c++ small linked list game keeps crashing

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have just started learning about linked lists and I am trying to create a small game with a few nodes. I have created 7 nodes and I am trying to create a little game where I can go from node to node until the user escapes my castle..The start of my game works good and so does the second level but once I get to the third level no matter what I choose I get NULL.This is my first time creating a little program like this so any tips for fixing the issue would be greatly appreciated.Here is my code so far...

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct ListNode
 {
 string text1;
 string text2;
 string text3;
 string text4;
 ListNode *right;
 ListNode *left;
 ListNode *up;
 ListNode *down;
 int choice;

ListNode()
 {
 text1 = "NULL";
 text2 = "NULL";
 text3= "NULL";
 text4= "NULL";
 right = NULL;
 left = NULL;
 up = NULL;
 down = NULL;
 choice = 1;
 }

 };

int main()
 {
 char choice;

ListNode *start = new ListNode();

ListNode *two = NULL;
 two = new ListNode();
 start->right = two;
 two->left = start;

ListNode *three = NULL;
 three = new ListNode();
 two->down = three;
 three->up = two;

ListNode *four = NULL;
 four = new ListNode();
 four->right = four;
 three->left = three;

ListNode *five = NULL;
 five = new ListNode();
 five->right = five;
 three->left = four;

ListNode *six = NULL;
 six = new ListNode();
 six->up = six;
 five->down = five;

ListNode *seven = NULL;
 seven = new ListNode();
 seven->up = seven;
 three->down = six;

start->text1 = "Welcome to my Castle.";
start->text2 = "You cannot leave!!";

two->text1 = "yay i'm in the second level!";
two->text2 = "Oh no, i'm at the second level again?";

three->text1= "yay, im on the third level";
three->text2= "Oh no, i'm at the third level again?";

four->text1= "yay, im on the fourth level";
four->text2= "Oh no, i'm at the fourth level again?";

five->text1= "yay, im on the fifth level";
five->text2= "Oh no, i'm at the fifth level again?";

six->text1= "yay, im on the sixth level";
six->text2= "Oh no, i'm at the sixth level again?";

seven->text1= "yay, im on the seventh level and have ESCAPED the castle";
seven->text2= "Oh no, i'm at the seventh level again?";



ListNode *ptr = start;

while (true)
 {
 if (ptr->choice == 1)
 {
 cout<<ptr->text1<<endl;
 ptr->choice = 2;
 }
 else
 cout<<ptr->text2<<endl;

if (ptr->up != NULL)
 {
 cout<<"Press w to go up"<<endl;
 }
 if (ptr->down != NULL)
 {
 cout<<"Press s to go down"<<endl;
 }
 if (ptr->left != NULL)
 {
 cout<<"Press a to go left"<<endl;
 }
 if (ptr->right != NULL)
 {
 cout<<"Press d to go right"<<endl;
 }
 cin>>choice;

if (choice == 'w')
 ptr = ptr->up;
 else if (choice == 's')
 ptr = ptr->down;
 else if (choice == 'a')
 ptr = ptr->left;
 else if (choice == 'd')
 ptr = ptr->right;
 else
 {
 cout<<"wrong input..  "<<choice<<" was not an option"<<endl;
 }

}


return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why did you tag Node.js?

Comment: There's a bracket which should not be there: `}*/ }; int main()`

Comment: What does _"I get NULL"_ mean?  An exception or SEGFAULT? Something else?

Comment: @JonathanCamenzind It belongs there; it closes the definition of the `struct ListNode`.

Comment: Oh of course i see it now

Comment: Yeah, the bracket belongs there. I had left a little example on there but I edited it..I tagged Node.js because the site recommended it. I am sorry about that, its my first time posting on here.

Comment: @pikProgram: Please post your full code to analyze.

Comment: In my program the user is supposed to go right first, then down, then left, etc... But once I get to the third level and go left my program displays the word NULL and crashes on me...I don't know how to get it to display "yay I made it to the third level" as opposed to saying NULL

Comment: this is my full code up to this point..I am trying to create a little linked list game that tells a little story..The user should be able to go from level to level until they complete the game...I plan to add up to 20 nodes but I don't understand how to make it work properly passed the first couple of levels

Comment: you need to test that the user entered a valid input e.g. if ((choice == 'w') && (ptr->up != NULL)) because even though you only print out the valid choices there's nothing to stop the user from entering a wrong one

Comment: also why not declare your ListNodes like this: ListNode *start = new ListNode(); ?

Comment: I edited my code and posted it..My program is working better but I am still having issues with the leveling up in my game...Every time I move from the fourth level to fifth level my program repeatedly says "Oh no I am back in the 4th level" and never progresses..Also, how can I control which options(ex. left, right, up, down) pop up for the user to choose from in different levels?

Answer (score 2):

> But once I get to the third level and go left my program displays the word NULL and crashes on me

Nowhere in the code is `text3` or `text4` ever printed. Therefore this...

```
three->text3= "yay, im on the third level";
three->text4= "Oh no, i'm at the second level again?";
```

should be this...

```
three->text1= "yay, im on the third level";
three->text2= "Oh no, i'm at the second level again?";
```

Comment: thanks that helped a lot...My program is working better but I am still having issues with the leveling up in my game...Every time I move from the fourth level to fifth level my program repeatedly says "Oh no I am back in the 4th level" and never progresses..Also, how can I control which options(ex. left, right, up, down) pop up for the user to choose from in different levels?

Comment: You don't have a node pointer to `five` anywhere in your code, therefore node 5 is inaccessible. Pedantic point: your data structure is a directed graph, not a linked list.

Comment: @pikProgram - Get a piece of paper and draw a box for each level with the number of the level in it. Go through your code and draw arrows between the boxes for each of 'right' 'left' 'up' 'down'. Then you might be able to work out what goes where. I suggest you also re-organize your code so that the 'right' 'left' 'up' 'down' for each level are listed directly below the line that 'new's that level.